# C++ empty String constructor

Tags: c++, string

I am a C++ beginner, so sorry if the question is too basic.

I have tried to collect the string constrcturs and try all them out (to remember them).

```
string strA();          // string(); empty string // incorrect
string strB("Hello");   // string( const char* str)
string strC("Hello",3); // string( const char* str, size_type length)
string strD(2,'c');     // string( size_type lenght, const char &c)
string strE(strB);      // string( const string& s)

cout << strA << endl;
cout << strB << endl;
cout << strC << endl;
cout << strD << endl;
cout << strE << endl;
```

All of them works except for the **strA**. It prints "1". **Why? Whats the type of the strA in this case? How can I check the type of stuff when I am unsure?**

I have noticed that the correct way is this (which by the way seems to be inconsistent with the other constructors, sometimes parens sometimes no parens):

```
string strA;
```

ps: question in bold, usual irrelevant answers will be downvoted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a very popular gotcha. C++ grammar is ambiguous. One of the rules to resolve ambiguities is "if something looks like declaration it is a declaration". In this case instead of defining a variable you declared a function prototype.

```
string strA();
```

is equivalent to

```
string strA(void);
```

a prototype of a no-arg function which returns string.

If you wish to explicitly call no-arg constructor try this:

```
string strA=string();
```

It isn't fully equivalent - it means 'create a temporary string using no-arg constructor and then copy it to initialize variable strA', but the compiler is allowed to optimize it and omit copying.

EDIT:
[Here is an appropriate item in C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2)

Comment: And this is one reason why I stopped using C++.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp : This bothered me, too. I guess this is the price paid to keep C compatibility. The alternative being using C, which has its metric ton of problems, my guess is that it's better to keep C++ and avoid that pitfall.

Comment: how about `std::string strA("");`

Answer (score 14):

It considers

```
string strA();
```

as a function declaration.

For default constructor use:

```
string strA;
```

Comment: You may use that notation when allocating off the heap:
string* strA = new string();

Answer (score 6):

In C++, as in C, there is a rule that says that anything that looks like a declarartion will be treated as a declaration.

```
string strA();
```

looks like a function declaration, so it is treated as one. You need:

```
string strA;
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that in this case, the rule "if it could be a declaration, it's taken to be a declaration" applies. Since in the following, *both* things are declarations

```
string a;
string a();
```

The one is the declaration of an object, and the other is the declaration of a function. The rule applies in other cases. For example, in this case:

```
string a(string());
```

In that case, `string()` can mean two things.

- Declaration of an unnamed function parameter
- Expression creating a default constructed `string`

The fule applies here, and `string()` is taken to mean the same as the following, named parameter (names are irrelevant in parameters when declaring a function)

```
string a(string im_not_relevant());
```

If a function takes as parameter an array or another function, that parameter decays into a pointer. In case of a function parameter, to a pointer to the function. Thus, it is equivalent to the following, which may look more familiar

```
string a(string (*im_not_relevant)());
```

But in your case, it's rather the syntax that's getting into the way. It's saying that the following is a function declaration. It can never be the declaration of an object (even though that was probably intended by the programmer!)

```
string a();
```

So there is no ambiguity in this context in the first place, and thus it declares a function. Since `string` has a user defined constructor, you can just omit the parentheses, and the effect remains the same as what was intended.

Answer (score 3):

It prints `1` because pointers to functions are always converted to numeric as `true`.

Comment: Only if the pointer to function is non-null. Anyway, a pointer to function should point to its definition, and that's missing here. This shouldn't have linked.

Answer (score 2):

tkopec is right on why it doesn't work. To answer your second question, here's how you check the type:

```
template<typename TEST> void Error_() {
   TEST* MakeError = 1;
}
```

By calling `Error_(StrA);` you will get a compile error, and your compiler will probably tell you that it happened in `Error_< std::basic_string<char, std::allocator<char> > (*)(void)>(std::basic_string<char, std::allocator<char> > (*)(void))`
Now, std::basic_string > is just std::string, so this really means `Error_< std::string (*)(void)> (std::string (*)(void))`. The part between '<>' is repeated between '()', and that's the sype of strA. In this case, `std::string (*)(void)`.

Comment: Type of strA is a function. std::string(void) . It's not a function pointer. He would have to declare it as string (*strA)(); if he wanted it to be a function pointer. I probably know what you meant, but your last sentences sound like you say it's a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler interprets `string strA()` as a function prototype of a function which takes void arguments and returns an object of string type. If you want to create a empty string object use `string strA;` (without paranthesis)