# boost disable_interruption not preventing thread_interrupted

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am trying to prevent interruption of a thread while it is in a particular scope. However, using `boost::this_thread::disable_interruption di()` does not seem to have any effect.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void worker() {
    std::cout << "START" << std::endl;

    for(;;) {
        {
            boost::this_thread::disable_interruption di();
            try {
                boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            }
            catch(boost::thread_interrupted & e) {
                assert( false );
            }
        }

        try {
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        }
        catch(boost::thread_interrupted & e) {
            break;
        }

    }

    std::cout << "END" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    boost::thread thread(&worker);
    thread.interrupt();
    thread.join();
}
```

The documentation appears to imply that `boost::this_thread::sleep()` will not throw `boost::thread_interrupted` while `di` is in scope.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove parenthesis in the following line:

```
//boost::this_thread::disable_interruption di();
boost::this_thread::disable_interruption di;
```

Instead of creating disable_interruption object, you declared function di.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem! Though, could you explain how it was declaring a function? `disable_interruption` is a type.

Comment: @Timesquare: it is an interesting issue. You can read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034606/is-there-any-use-for-local-function-declarations).