# use of std::less in std::map does not compile

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, most-vexing-parse

I am unable to understand why does following function not compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(){
  std::map<int, int, std::less<int>> myMap(std::less<int>());
  myMap[2] = 2;
  std::cout << myMap[2] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The error message is as follows -

```
std_less_check.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
std_less_check.cpp:6:10: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   myMap[2] = 2;
          ^
std_less_check.cpp:6:14: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(myMap + 2)’
   myMap[2] = 2;
              ^
std_less_check.cpp:6:14: error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘std::map<int, int, std::less<int> >(std::less<int> (*)())’ in assignment
std_less_check.cpp:7:23: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
   std::cout << myMap[2] << std::endl;
```

while following compiles successfully

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(){
  std::map<int, int, std::less<int>> myMap(std::less<int>{});
  myMap[2] = 2;
  std::cout << myMap[2] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Fails to compile how exactly? What is the actual error message? There should be no difference between using `()` vs `{}` when constructing a `std::less` object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's what I thought. But doesn't seem to be the case. I have edited the question with error message.

Comment: is there a reason why you are using `std::less` explicitly to begin with? It is already the default comparer for `std::map`, so you don’t need to use it explicitly in this code: `std::map<int, int> myMap;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using std::less to reproduce the error. In my actual code, I am using a custom comparator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first program, you have a vexing parse. If the compiler can parse a declaration as either a variable or a function, it will choose to parse it as a function.

`myMap` can be parsed as a function declaration.

It returns a `std::map<int, int, std::less<int>>`.

It takes an argument of type `std::less<int>()`, which is itself a function type that returns a `std::less<int>` and takes no arguments. Note that you can't actually have a function type as an argument; the type is actually a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns a `std::less<int>`.

---

In the second program, replacing `()` with `{}` resolves the ambiguity. Now `myMap` can no longer be a function declaration, and so it instead declares a variable of type `std::map<int, int, std::less<int>>`.

Comment: `takes an argument of type std::less<int>()` Note that the parameter is adjusted to be a pointer to `std::less<int>()` similar to how an array parameter would be adjusted to be a pointer to element of such array.

Comment: @eerorika I'm not sure I follow. The parameter is a function type of the form `T()`, right?

Comment: A function is not an object; there are no values of function types. A function cannot be "passed by value" - just like an array cannot be "passed by value". When you write a function declaration with an array parameter, the parameter is adjusted to be a pointer (to element of such array). When you write a function declaration with a function parameter, the parameter is adjusted to be a pointer (to such function). As such, there are no functions that accept a function type nor functions that accepts an array type even though you can declare such functions. Such declarations are *adjusted*.

Comment: @eerorika Oh, I see. Yes, that's true, but is it necessary to use that terminology? I think I've heard of functions being described as having array types and function types as parameters. Even though, as you point out, those types will get adjusted to pointers.

Comment: It's useful to mention it because not everyone reading the answer are aware of these adjustment rules.

Comment: @cigien I understand there is an ambiguity between a function declaration and a variable. But wait, in C++, we can't declare functions within function. Does that not disambiguate it?

Comment: @atuly `in C++, we can't declare functions within function.` You've assumed wrongly. In C++, we **can** declare functions within function.

Comment: @atuly Actually, in C++ you can't *define* a function inside a function, but you can declare it.

Comment: Oh I see. Could you please point me to some use case of declaring a function within a function but not defining it there?

Comment: @eerorika That's a good point. Added, thanks.

Comment: @atuly Here's a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034606/is-there-any-use-for-local-function-declarations