# Why dynamic_cast from reference causes a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

I have an `expr_t` base class, from which `ident_t` is derived. I wrote some `to_string` overloads to display differently between `expr_t` and `ident_t`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct expr_t {
  virtual ~expr_t() {}
};

struct ident_t : public expr_t {
  std::string name;

  ident_t(std::string name) : name(name) {}
};
std::string to_string(expr_t& v) {
  if (auto* id = dynamic_cast<ident_t*>(&v)) {
    return to_string(*id);
  }
  return "error";
}
std::string to_string(ident_t& v) {
  return v.name;
}

int main() {
  expr_t* b = new ident_t("c");
  std::cout << to_string(*b) << std::endl; // segfault
  delete b;
  return 0;
}
```

However, no output is generated and seg-fault occurs when debugging with GDB.

Comment: You get a stack overflow because `std::string to_string(expr_t& v)` doesn't see the other overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that at the point of the call `return to_string(*id)` the compiler doesn't have a declaration for the second overload `std::string to_string(ident_t& v)`.  Thus the same first version will be recursively called eventually resulting in a seg fault.

To **solve** this you can either move the second overload's definition before the first overload or forward declare the second overload before the definition of the first overload as shown below:

```
//moved the 2nd overload above first overload
std::string to_string(ident_t& v) {
  return v.name;
}

std::string to_string(expr_t& v) {
  if (auto* id = dynamic_cast<ident_t*>(&v)) {
    return to_string(*id); //now compiler knows about std::string to_string(ident_t& v)
  }
  return "error";
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/CVXpYTz7C)

##### Method 2

```
//forward declaration for 2nd overload
std::string to_string(ident_t& v);

std::string to_string(expr_t& v) {
  if (auto* id = dynamic_cast<ident_t*>(&v)) {
    return to_string(*id); //now compiler knows about std::string to_string(ident_t& v)
  }
  return "error";
}
//definition for 2nd overload
std::string to_string(ident_t& v) {
  return v.name;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/UxueSUTmT)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, at the point where you call (or *try* to call) the version of `to_string` that takes an `ident_t&` argument, there has been neither definition nor declaration of such an overload. Thus, that call becomes infinitely recursive, causing (eventually) a crash.

To resolve the issue either: (a) move the definition of the `ident_t&`-taking overload to *before* the `expr_t&` version; or (b) at least provide a **declaration** of that overload before the call:

```cpp
std::string to_string(ident_t& v); // Declaration of the other version ...
std::string to_string(expr_t& v)
{
    if (auto* id = dynamic_cast<ident_t*>(&v)) {
        return to_string(*id);     // ... which can now be used here!
    }
    return "error";
}
```

(You *could* even add that declaration *immediately* before the call – i.e. inside the `if (auto* id ...)` block; however, although such [local function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1034606/10871073) are technically legal, many C++ programmers don't like them.)