# Why C++ 'Standard' won't support function definition inside another function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have search through google/stack overflow etc. but I could not find the proper/exact solution for this. I know latest C++ revision supports Lambda function by which we can achieve, and also I know we should avoid defining a function inside another function. But I'm curious why can not we have function definition inside function according to C++ standard?.

like following:

```
int print() {
   void test(){
     // statements
   }
}
```

I know people will mark this as duplicate but in those questions no one has given satisfactory answer, to make this to be highlight I have asked here.

Comment: What's the point if you have lambdas?

Comment: I  mean we can define function using them

Comment: Because it didn't see the use in this without some sort of closure mechanic. Which we now have, they are called lambdas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967202/why-cant-i-define-a-function-inside-another-function

Comment: Because it requires special hardware to implement: either a display or a load-address instruction. I haven't seen a language that allowed this since 1982.

Comment: yeah that's correct @StoryTeller. But Im just curious why we cannot?

Comment: I don't know what kind of answer you expect for this kind of question. It's always *"Because that's what the committee decided."* Write a mail to Stroustrup if you want to ask him why he did not decide differently. vOv

Comment: @BaummitAugen So you are saying this question is useless?

Comment: @Suchendra I would not go as far as calling it "insane", but in the end you are asking us why some group of people made a particular choice. Hard to tell for people who are not part of said group. ("insane" changed to "useless", and that I would agree with.)

Comment: Since you can write `auto test = []{ statements; };` and call it as a function, pretty much yeah

Comment: @EJP why would it require special hardware? I can see a nested function easily implemented like a normal function but with a special access, so that it can be called only from the enclosing function (well... I imagine no closure for them)

Comment: @bolov Thats right +1

Comment: @bolov It requires special hardware if the nested function accesses a variable declared in the enclosing function, bearing in mind that the nested function could call itself recursively.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: At least some of those people frequent this tag, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough. And there are also mailing lists, talks and what not, so admittedly, those questions can be answered. I did not vote this to be off-topic.

Comment: Deffo dupe tho.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's not

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What is this world we are living in!! If we ask curious questions , we get negative remarks. If you know answer please do. Im waiting for the answer, not for the arguments.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I think I wont get answer from you.

Comment: @Suchendra: The detailed, freely-written answer is on the duplicate question that we kindly marked for you in our own time. What is this world we are living in, where people are so lazy and entitled? I'm waiting for a little effort and gratitude on your part!

Comment: Thank you for all who tried to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered now that you could emulate it in the pre c++11 days like this:

```
void foo() {
  struct detail {
    static void bar() {
      //statements
    }
  };

  detail::bar();
}
```

Can even pass that as a callback from within `foo`. You should note however that there is no closure here. You can't access variables of `foo` in `bar`.

Comment: We can achieve it by your solution which you've provided. But my question why we cannot define a function inside another? Is there any particular reason Does it effects the efficiency or performance?

Comment: @Suchendra, without any closure mechanic it doesn't affect any metric of the program, other than code clarity.

Answer (score -2):

Pretty sure you can:

```
int main() {
    auto curry = [] (auto f) {
        return [=] (auto x) {
            return [=] (auto y) {
                return f(x, y);
            };
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: OP asks explicitly not about lambdas.