# Sort function does not work with function object created on stack?

Tags: c++, sorting, functor

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
class Integer
    {
public:
    int m;
    Integer(int a):m(a){};
    };
class CompareParts
    {
    public:
        bool operator()(const Integer & p1,const Integer & p2)
            {
            return p1.m<p2.m;
            }
    }obj1;
int main()
    {
    std::vector<Integer> vecInteger;
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(12));
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(13));
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(5));
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(7));
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(9));
    Integer obj2();
    std::sort(vecInteger.begin(),vecInteger.end(),obj1);
    std::sort(vecInteger.begin(),vecInteger.end(),obj2);
    }
```

why is obj2 in second sort function leads to compiler error.

Comment: Be sure to add the compile error to the question.  That will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: "Sort function does not with function object created on stack?"

You're missing a word in the title. I had to click through to see you meant COMPILE rather than WORK.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Integer obj2()` isn't the definition of an object, it is the declaration of a function named `obj2` returning an `Integer` (put it outside any function to understand why it is so).  This occurs also sometimes with more complex constructions where it can be even more confusing. Some name this the *most vexing parse*.

Here is the promised example of a more complex case:

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar { Bar(Foo); };

Bar quxx(Foo()); // quxx is a function
```

Here `quxx` is a function returning a Bar and taking (a pointer) to a function returning a Foo and without parameters.  You could write the same declaration more clearly like this:

```
Bar quxx(Foo (*fn)()); // quxx is the same function as above
```

To get the definition of a variable initialized with the constructor taking a Foo, you can add a level of parenthesis:

```
Bar quux((Foo())); // quux is a variable
```

Comment: Yes, and the correct syntax is "Integer obj2;". Add to that the fact that you probably wanted to create a CompareParts object, and you should be closer to results.

Comment: Um, sure it's right. The point where a declaration appears is not necessary the point where the entity it declares lives. In this case, it declares a global function, using a local declaration.

Comment: AProgrammer is correct - it's a function declaration. And yes, you cn declare a function inside another function.

Comment: @Chickencha  C++ takes from C the overriding rule that if something can possibly be parsed as a declaration, it will be parsed as a declaration.

Comment: @Chickencha, it is a *declaration* not a *definition*.  It is quite old fashioned and you'll rarely see that in C++ and in modern C, but it is still valid and quite common in older code.  AFAIR the 1st ed of K&R used it for instance.

Comment: Okay, after looking into this a little more you guys are right. (Comments deleted to prevent misguiding people.) I could've sworn that I've seen instances of classes declared this way, but apparently not. Oh well, I learned something new today.

Comment: Some comment from the Standard: `8.5 Initializers /8`: *"[Note: since **`()`** is not permitted by the syntax for initializer, **`X a();`** is not the declaration of an object of class **`X`**, but the declaration of a function taking no argument and returning an **`X`**. The form **`()`** is permitted in certain other initialization contexts (5.3.4, 5.2.3, 12.6.2). ]"* Hope that explains the matter.

Comment: To complement litb comment: 5.3.4 -> new X(), 5.2.3 -> in an expression, says X x = X(), -> 12.6.2 -> in initialization list.  About the case of an expression, note that the use in subexpressions in other constructors calls can lead to the ambiguity and the choice of a function declaration instead of a variable definition.  I'll add an example.

Comment: @Neil, well both versions are declarations. You may stick "extern" in front of it, and would get a non-defining object declaration if it weren't a function. The reason for this is, that there is no ambiguity at all. It's just a function declaration, not anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Because obj2 is a function. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925513/c-empty-string-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

obj2 is not a BinaryPredicate and is invalid as the third parameter to std::sort

obj2 needs to be something like

```
// Return whether first element is greater than the second
bool UDgreater ( int elem1, int elem2 )
{
   return elem1 > elem2;
}
```

or the functor type used by obj1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definition of no argument constructor.

Use, Integer obj2(0);

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
class Integer
{
     public:
     int m;
     Integer(int a):m(a){};
     bool operator()(const Integer p1,const Integer p2)
     {
      return p1.m<p2.m;
     }
};
class CompareParts
{    public:
     bool     operator()(const Integer  p1,const Integer p2)
     {
         return p1.m<p2.m;
         }
}obj1;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Integer> vecInteger;
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(12));
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(13));
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(5));
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(7));
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(9));
    Integer obj2(0);
    std::sort(vecInteger.begin(),vecInteger.end(),obj1);
    std::sort(vecInteger.begin(),vecInteger.end(),obj2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
```

class Integer
{

public:
    int m;
    Integer(int a):m(a){};
};

class CompareParts 
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Integer & p1,const Integer & p2)
    {
        return p1.m
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector vecInteger;  
 
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(12));
 
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(13)); 
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(5));  
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(7));  
    vecInteger.push_back(Integer(9));

```
std::sort(vecInteger.begin(),vecInteger.end(),CompareParts()); 
typedef vector<Integer>::const_iterator Iter;
Iter beg = vecInteger.begin();
Iter end = vecInteger.end();

for (Iter iter = beg; iter != end; ++iter)
    cout << (*iter).m << " ";

cout << endl;
```

}

Output:
5 7 9 12 13